# How to create desktop applications using python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

I have been writing desktop application in c# and of the experience of writing my code in VS, compiling it and let .NET framework do the running and execution.

Now I want to develop desktop applications using python. I am new to python.

Speaking of UI programming, please suggest which framework is best for rich desktop app programming and why, remember I'm coming from a tool like WPF. Also Please suggest any useful tutorials to start developing desktop applications using Python.

Comment: http://ironpython.net

Comment: Basic answer is you have to use a library, for example Qt, via PyQt. But this question is too broad, and this is also very easy to google.

Comment: I agree with Preet, maybe PyQt should be 1st choice, as it is not only about GUI, but also cover QtCore(about the string and container),  QtXML, QtNetwork and so on, the API is very rich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that answers will be very subjective.

If you are not familiar with python, I suggest you to try few different tutorials and books. If you have experiance with C#, may be Python reference will be good for you: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/ Also, python documentation is pretty good.

After you become more or less familiar with python, than try different Python UI frameworks. Find some 5 popular fremeworks, compare their advantages and disadvantages in terms of problem you are going to solve.

Than just try few of this five. Also lots of popular python books contain chapters about python applications with GUI.

I'm now sure if StackOverflow rules are allow to suggest any specific books. Here the list for python UI frameworks (with a short description): https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Comment: "I think that answers will be very subjective." then why are you providing one? If the answers will be subjective you should vote to close (or flag, if you cannot vote).

Comment: My fault, I've not specified my point about subjectivity. Looks like we can see here two questions: 'how to learn python' and 'which framefork is the best'. I think that unswers to the question "which framework is best" will be subjective. But, on the second hand, @rathodr trying to find out where to start his learning way, and as for me, this question is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for PyQt and Tkinter.